# Error with lambda in operator<< of template class with default argument

Tags: c++

Can someone enlighten me what is going wrong with this code:

```
template<typename B=int> // <<<< =int is provoking the error
struct Foo
{
    std::array<B,10> data;

    template<typename F>
    void iterate(F f) const
    {
        for(unsigned i=0; i<10; i++) {
            f(i, data[i]);
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo<B>& a) // Line 17
    {
        a.iterate([&os](unsigned i, const B& x) {
            os << i << "=" << x << "\n";
        });
        return os;
    }
};
```

Error message with GCC 4.8.1 and `--std=c++11`:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo<B>&)’:
test.cpp:17:41: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo<B>&)::__lambda0’
   a.iterate([&os](unsigned i, const B& x) {
```

Comment: Do you have a forward declaration of the template (or the friend function) somewhere?

Comment: Try xhanging it to a `template` friend, might make error change or go away.

Comment: @AlanStokes: No. It is just this code (with std includes and an empty main).

Comment: moving `operator<<` out of the `struct Foo` makes the error disappears, however I do not know why:( Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071130/default-argument-for-template-parameter-for-class-enclosing - maybe answers have explanation...

Comment: In the `operator <<`, you can just declare `a` as `const Foo &` (the `<B>` is redundant). Which might help - or might not. Very mysterious.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Good to know, but the error prevails.

Comment: One option is to make the friend function not relying on the same `typename` used by the struct: `template<typename C> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo<C>& a)`. http://ideone.com/AMj6lm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.iterate([&os](unsigned i, const B& x) {
    os << i << "=" << x << "\n";
});
```

The lambda function introduced here has the effect of declaring an "unnamed" local class at function scope within the `operator<<` function body. We can write our own functor object to get a similar effect:

```
struct lambda {
    std::ostream& os;

    lambda(std::ostream& os_) : os(os_) {}

    void operator()(unsigned i, const B& x) {
        os << i << "=" << x << "\n";
    }
};
a.iterate(lambda(os));
```

This elicits a similar error from g++:

```
error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing
       ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo<B>&)::lambda::lambda’
```

Here is an SSCCE:

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Foo
{
    friend void f() {
        struct local {};
    }
};
```

And the error it elicits:

```
error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing
       ‘f()::local::local’
```

This was already reported as [GCC bug 57775](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57775).

As pointed out by @PiotrNycz, you can work around by moving the body of the function `operator<<` outside of the class template.